# ¿Cómo obtener una lista agrupando valores de un diccionario?

Tags: python

Como puedo hacer para que los `países` salgan en un `conjunto` y no se repitan como es el caso de `Alemania`.

```
goleadores_2014={
 "Muller": ("Alemania",5),
 "Dempsey": ("USA",2),
 "James": ("Colombia",6),
 "Schurrle": ("Alemania",3),
 "Messi":("Argentina",4),
 "Suarez": ("Uruguay",2),
 "van Persie":("Holanda",4),
 "Benzema": ("Francia",3),
 "Klose": ("Alemania",2),
 "Robben": ("Holanda", 3), 
 "Valencia": ("Ecuador",3),
 "Neymar": ("Brasil",4),
 "Shaqiri": ("Suiza",3), 
 "Kroos": ("Alemania",2),
 "Luiz": ("Brasil",2)
}

maximo = 0
goleador = ' '
for i in goleadores_2014:
  goles = goleadores_2014[i][1]
  if goles >= maximo:
    maximo = goles
    goleador = i
print("==================Goleador================")
print("El goleador es " + str(goleador) + " con " + str(maximo) + " goles")

print("===============Paises del mundial====================")
paises=goleadores_2014.values( )
for i in paises:
  print(i[0])
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más simple es creando un objeto [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset) a partir de la lista (con repeticiones) de los países, un [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset) es una colección desordenada de elementos únicos:

```
> print(set(e[0] for e in goleadores_2014.values()))

set(['Brasil', 'USA', 'Alemania', 'Francia', 'Holanda', 'Uruguay', 'Suiza', 'Colombia', 'Argentina', 'Ecuador'])
```

- En primer lugar extraemos todos los países mediante comprensión: `e[0] for e in goleadores_2014.values()`
- Luego creamos un `set` a partir del conjunto total de paises, el `set` contendrá los valores únicos
- Por último, recuerda que el resultado final no respetará ningún orden en particular.

Si preferimos que la salida sea una lista, simplemente hay que volver a convertir el `set`:

```
> print(list(set(e[0] for e in goleadores_2014.values())))
```

Comment: No hace falta crear dentro de set la lista. Basta con set(e[0] ...values())

Comment: @JoséMiguelSA, es cierto, un generador en definitiva es un iterable, buen comentario.